# Can I leverage the Qt Meta-Object system in PyQt like I can in PythonQt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I know in PythonQt I can access MOC'd QObject based classes in Python code and that python code can be executed from C++. Is it possible to do something similar using PyQt or is it intended to be used only to write Qt in Python?

I understand SIP is used to expose C/C++ code to Python but that doesn't seem to be as elegant as using the meta-object system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/Features.html), but after a brief skim of the features, it seems that, in terms of conceptual emphasis, it really should have been called QtPython.

PyQt started life as a tool for prototyping Qt C++ applications in python. As a consequence, it was originally a *very* thin wrapper around the Qt library, which made it almost trivial to port Qt code from python to C++ and vice versa. And it still is quite easy to do this. But since PyQt4, the emphasis has shifted strongly towards making it easier to write Qt applications in Python; and with PyQt5, it has moved even further in that direction.

So PyQt is now intended purely for writing Qt applications in python (and the same goes for PySide). It does not provide any facility for executing python code within C++ (other than indirectly via virtual functions). If you need to expose third-party Qt classes to python, you would need to wrap them using Sip.

As for the meta-object system: PyQt does wrap [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) and so forth, but there is not enough information in your question to know whether that would be of any use to you.